# Why SwiftUI List returns back when I add reference to selected object in the next step?

Tags: swiftui, core-data

**Question:**
What is the best approach to avoid SwiftUI list returning back to beginning, when I save viewContext after adding reference from selected object to a child item?

**How it should work:**
Idea is that user select Item_general from SwiftUI List or creates his own Item_general on a Sheet, then he selects Item_ocurrence or creates an Item_size and in next step remaining properties that creates Item_ocurrence.

> Item_general is one to many: Item_ocurrence

> Item_ocurrence is many to one: Item_size

My list of Item_general is defined as follows:

```
    private var items_request: FetchRequest<Item_general>
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item_general>{items_request.wrappedValue}//FetchedResults<Item_general>
....
    init(categoryGUID: UUID) {
        self.categoryFilterString = categoryGUID.uuidString
        self.items_request = FetchRequest(entity: Item_general.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item_general.name, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "category.guid = %@", self.categoryFilterString))
    }
....    

   var body: some View {
        
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink {
                                // It may be null right after deleting object
                                ItemOccurrenceSearchView(item: item, item_guid: item.guid!, shouldSynchronizeGlobally: true)
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(item.icon ?? "")
                                    Text(item.name ?? "")
                                }
                            }
```

**The problem found:**
Everything worked well when I simply had one-side relation, from Item_occurrence to Item_general. But I started creating inversions to CoreData objects. When created inversion on Item_general to have links to many Item_ocurrence, then adding relations by

```
item.addToItem_ocurrence(newOccurrence)
```

after saving Item_ocurrence, list returns back to beginning. Why? I'm not modifying Item_general, just its child relations that are not yet selected.

```
            let newSize = Item_size(context: viewContext)
            
            newSize.guid = UUID()
            newSize.weight_gram = Int32(weight_gram)
            newSize.capacity_milliliter = Int32(capacity_volume)
            newSize.amount = Int32(amount)
            
            let newOccurrence = Item_occurrence(context: viewContext)
            newOccurrence.guid = UUID()
            newOccurrence.kcal = 0

            newSize.addToItem_ocurrence(newOccurrence)

            // this line makes my list going back to select of Item_general
            item.addToItem_ocurrence(newOccurrence)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
            }
```

I checked memory addresses of the items that user selects and they are not changing after saving db context. The view id also is not changing. Regardless of whether I add Item_general.guid as the view Id, or leave it unassigned the problem is only when there is inversion on Item_general and I add relation using `item.addToItem_ocurrence(newOccurrence)`.

Temporarily I removed inversion on Item_general to Item_ocurrence and removed
`item.addToItem_ocurrence(newOccurrence)` and relate objects simply this way: `newOccurrence.item = item`

Anyway I feel I should create this inversion and find a way to not invalidate the parent list of items. Any help would be welcome. Thank you for your time reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find exactly what I wanted, but had to change few things in my approach:

- don't work directly on NSManagedObject classes for editing between different views, rather work with ViewModels structs
- save context on the end, not every step

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).